Modulo on ARM SIMD Aarch64 (NEON)
I am learning about ARM-v8 Aarch64 SIMD instructions hoping I can optimize some calculations. In this case, I am looking for modulo operation on a 4xf32 vector.
How can I implement a modulo with the NEON instruction set?
Note: I actually am looking for something to make sure my angle values stay between -PI and +PI (cyclical, not clamping), so I am also interested in other solutions for that.
Note: currently I am trying to do it with the arm_neon.h header in C, but I might at some point do it directly with assembly for even more optimization of combining instructions without storing the results in variables.

Clamping floats or doubles in SIMD with min and max operations is going to be a lot simpler than integer modulus operation.

Eh, ok. But I am asking about floating point modulus. On integer modulus, at least I know some tricks to do it.

Sorry, I missed it was modulus on floats. Can you not just do x mod y = x - y * (floor(x/y)), casting to integers and back for floor? I'm not that familiar with NEON.

As for intrinsics: the compiler usually does a pretty good job, so unless you know that the assembly code is bad, you don't really need to drop to the assembly level.  However, for learning, there'll still be value in doing so anyway.

@SimonGoater yes, that was how I was going to solve it if there wasn't a better solution. Seems there isn't. Thanks.

@fuz I wonder about that, it is certainly worth investigating. Gcc is able to optimize (greatly) its own generated standard code because it knows about the instructions it uses, but as soon as you start injecting your own instructions I don't know if it will be able to optimize that.

The Armv8-A ASIMD instruction set extension does not have a modulo instruction, neither for floating point, nor for integer.  However, for a divisor of 1, you can emulate modulo by rounding the number using a “convert to integer” and then subtracting from the rounded number, giving you the fractional part with the appropriate sign.  You can then implement your modulo operation by these identities:
fmod(a, 1) = a - round_towards_zero(a)
fmod(a, b) = fmod(a/b, 1) * b

Note that in your case, b is a constant, so this becomes:
fmod(a, b) = a - round_towards_zero(a * 1/b) * b

This then becomes three instructions: a multiplication of a and 1/b, a “round towards zero” and a “multiply and subtract” operation.  For even better performance you should consider keeping your angles pre-scaled such that they are in the open interval of (−1, +1).
Another thing to consider: if it is known that the angles are out of range by at most b, it might be faster to instead compare with ±b and add/subtract b conditionally if needed.

That was how I was going to solve it, but I'm a bit disappointed. Thanks!

Modulus of floating point numbers just isn’t that common an operation.
